# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: new__post_user_post.user_id error after migrat

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-authentication, django-users

**I try to add postUser field to my existing models. When I tried to migrate, I am getting an error :django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: new__post_user_post.user_id**

**This is my model.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class TaskCategory(models.Model):
    category_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
    return self.category_title

class Post(models.Model):
   postUser = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE) **I try to add this fild**
   task_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   task_discription = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   task_category = models.ForeignKey(TaskCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   recommended_tools = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   budget = models.IntegerField(default=0)

   def __str__(self):
        return self.task_title + ' | ' + self.task_discription + ' | ' + str(self.task_category) + ' | ' + self.recommended_tools + ' | ' + str(self.budget) + ' | ' + str(self.id)

  def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

****Before I added one user, I already had admin and a number of posts created without postUser. Now in User table a have two users admin and one user.
When I run makemigrations, I was asked:
C:\Users\Davor\Desktop\suit>python manage.py makemigrations
You are trying to change the nullable field 'postUser' on post to non-nullable without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:

1. Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
2. Ignore for now, and let me handle existing rows with NULL myself (e.g. because you added a RunPython or RunSQL operation to handle NULL values in a previous data migration)
3. Quit, and let me add a default in models.py**

****Select an option: 1
Please enter the default value now, as valid Python
The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so you can do e.g. timezone.now
Type 'exit' to exit this prompt**

**admin**

**Invalid input: name 'admin' is not defined
Anybody knows how to fix this?******

Comment: try setting `default=1` on the foreign key this would set the foreign key of the existing posts to the user having `pk=1`. Then after migrating remove this and migrate again.

Comment: I did that, makemigrations are successful  but still getting an error when I run migrate:
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: new__post_user_post.user_id

Comment: @Davor_Python: that is because there is no `User` with primary key `1`, you need to set it to the primary key of an *existing* user.